# Motion RAW Videos possible?

Tags: raw, video

Sorry for the rushed question I don't have time.

So my good old DSC W610 could  shoot MJPEG but I always wanted an RAW video so I could make wallpapers from the scenery videos I Shoot.

Is this possible? I want to shoot FHD 30FPS Raw video.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87608/discussion-between-dr-mayhem-and-jonathan-irons).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This camera can't shoot RAW for still, not talking about video. And according to the specifications this camera can shoot 640x480x30 which is not very much by contemporary measures.

For shooting RAW video you should jump to much higher class cameras.

About DSLRs I found on [this site](https://wolfcrow.com/blog/a-comparison-of-seven-cheap-raw-cameras-for-video/) [sample table](https://wolfcrow.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/RAWComparisonCameras2.jpg) with cheapest DSLRs for RAW video:

Answer (score 2):

An FHD image has 2Mpixels.  A raw image from that would have 6MB.  At 30FPS, you are talking about 180MB/s sustained data rate.

What media were you planning to use?

Comment: I dunno mane maybeh SVHS